# Element on click changes google maps styles

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to change Google Maps' styles when user clicks an anchor. To accomplish this, I'm trying to make a simple alert work inside `addListener` but it doesn't seem to work.

html

```
<a href="" id="click-me">click me</a>
```

js

```
...

google.maps.event.addListener(document.getElementById('click-me'), 'click', function(){
    alert('asdf');
});

...
```

What am I doing wrong?

Obs 1: I also tried to use `preventDefault()`.

Obs 2: The anchor is already inside DOM. It isn't dynamically inserted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the listener is on a DOM element, use addDomListener, not addListener.  Change:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(document.getElementById('click-me'), 'click', function(){
    alert('asdf');
});
```

To:

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementById('click-me'), 'click', function(){
    alert('asdf');
});
```